# How can I set up 2 rails apps which share users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run 2 ruby on rails apps which share users, creating one app to do it all is not an option unfortunately. So I want to have single sign on, and user data shared across them. I'm unsure as to what the best solution to this would be.

Should I run them both off the same database?

Have 2 databases with both apps using the users table in one database only?

Some other solution?

Comment: You mean a single sign-on (SSO) solution like OAuth?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. I mean more so that user data can be shared between the apps and updated from either app, while staying in sync.

Comment: Having two apps on the same database can be tricky to coordinate, so you might want to split it into three apps, one of which is very small and "owns" the user database exclusively, plus provides login facilities where required.

Comment: I agree. The cleanest solution is to make a 3rd app which is the sole communicator with the database, and exposes an API of CRUD operations for the other two apps to consume. This way you avoid race conditions, and don't have to worry at all about the 2 user-facing apps knowing anything about each other or their separate database interactions.

Comment: you can use that for the 3rd app: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have a dedicated development rails environment to manage migrations. And have the two "apps" pointing at this database. The downside is just generating models and relationships twice for those two apps is a manual task.

A cleaner solution is to have one rails environment with migrations, models and relationships. But build an API endpoint into this environment that those two apps can call in order to use the shared database.